# Find if a String is present in an array

Tags: java, arrays

OK let's say I have an array filled with {"tube", "are", "fun"} and then I have a JTextField and if I type either one of those commands to do something and if NOT to get like a message saying "Command not found".

I tried looking in Java docs but all I am getting is things that I don't want like questions and stuff... so, how is this done? I know there is a "in array" function but I'm not too good with combining the two together.

Thanks.

Here is what I have so far:

```
String[] dan = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Orange", "Blue"};
boolean contains = dan.contains(say.getText());
```

but I am getting cannot find symbol in dan.contains

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
List<String> dan = Arrays.asList("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Orange", "Blue");

boolean contains = dan.contains(say.getText());
```

If you have a list of **not repeated** values, prefer using a `Set<String>` which has the same [contains](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method

Comment: That's because an array is not a set

Comment: @Dan - BZZZT - you are trying to invoke `contains` on an array, not a `Set`!!!

Comment: THANKS SIMPSO- I MEAN PABLO! :D Tahnks Stephen. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 40):

```
String[] a= {"tube", "are", "fun"};
Arrays.asList(a).contains("any");
```

Comment: THIS is what I was looking for. Simple !

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Arrays.asList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) to wrap the array in a `List<String>`, which does have a [`contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method:

```
Arrays.asList(dan).contains(say.getText())
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be done in java 8 using Stream.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

String[] stringList = {"Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Orange", "Blue"};

boolean contains = Stream.of(stringList).anyMatch(x -> x.equals(say.getText());
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  The others fail because `asList` returns non-parameterized generic.

Answer (score 1):

If you can organize the values in the array in sorted order, then you can use `Arrays.binarySearch()`.  Otherwise you'll have to write a loop and to a linear search.  If you plan to have a large (more than a few dozen) strings in the array, consider using a Set instead.

Comment: Erm, would it matter if I said that the array would be permnant and not changed at a order at all? Would there be an easier way than?

Comment: @Dan - I think his first sentence answers that.  You do know how to sort strings by hand, don't you?

Comment: @Jim, this answer is incorrect. The documentation of `#binarySearch` explicitly states: "If the array contains elements that are not mutually comparable (for example, strings and integers), it cannot be sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements, hence results are undefined." *DO NOT* use `binarySearch` on `Integer` or `String`, or any elements that can at most have a partial order.